# trying to add Azure B2c authentication to Asp.net core with React.js and Redux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, react-redux, azure-ad-b2c

I created a Asp.net core with React.js and Redux in virtual studio 2019. I did some change  to   configure the B2C authentication with Azuer , changes are startup.cs, appsettings.json and
in NavMenu.tsx as follows

```
        // Configuration to sign-in users with Azure AD B2C
        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");

        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        services.AddRazorPages();

        //Configuring appsettings section AzureAdB2C, into IOptions
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
        
         public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
         {
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
         }
```

in the appsettings

```
 "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://xxxxx.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "90cxxxx-bxxxx-44xxx-8xxx-xxxx0b29xxx",
    "Domain": "fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_xxxxx",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "b2c_1_xxx",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "b2c_1_xxx",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "b2c_1_xxxxx" // Optional profile editing policy
    //"CallbackPath": "/signin/B2C_1_sign_up_in"  // defaults to /signin-oidc
  },
```

in the NavMenu.tsx i  tried like this.. i did copy the asp code to .tsx and it didn't work

```
 <NavItem>
          <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" >
                <form method="get" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">
                       <button type="submit" >Sign Up/In</button>
                </form>
           </NavLink>
   </NavItem>
```

need a direction to fix this issue

Comment: please refer to https://medium.com/@fiqriismail/how-to-secure-your-reactjs-frontend-with-azure-ad-b2c-8fd165f602e8

Comment: Does the below answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to setup code like this. You can directly integrate Azure AD B2C with React.js and Redux.

*Pls follow step by step process of doing this: [React JS Application with Azure AD B2C](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/react-js-application-with-azure-id-b2c/)*

Comment: Does this help you?